# How to pass article id to pangination page with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am trying to do a pagination for category result page which is listing articles with ajax.
I use where clause and need to pass article id to the ajax page.

My codes : ajax.php

```
include_once '../db.php'; 
include_once '../class/Articles.php'; 
$ArticleHandler = new Articles($pdo);

if (!(isset($_GET['pageNumber']))) {
    $pageNumber = 1;
} else {
    $pageNumber = $_GET['pageNumber'];
}

$perPageCount = 5;
$catid = $_POST['article_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pcat = ?";
$posts = $ArticleHandler->getPosts($sql, [$catid])->fetchAll();
if ($posts !== '0') {
   $rowCount = $ArticleHandler->getPosts("SELECT count(*) FROM posts")->fetchColumn();
}

$pagesCount = ceil($rowCount/$perPageCount);

$lowerLimit = ($pageNumber - 1) * $perPageCount;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pcat = :pcat ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT :offset, :limit"; 
$results = $ArticleHandler->getPosts($sql, array(':pcat'=>$catid, ':offset'=>$lowerLimit, ':limit'=>$perPageCount))->fetchAll();

?>

<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
<tr>
  <th align="center">Name</th>
  <th align="center">Experience<br>(in years)
  </th>
  <th align="center">Subject</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($results as $data) { ?>
<tr>
  <td align="left"><?php echo $data['ptitle'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>

<div style="height: 30px;"></div>
<table width="50%" align="center">
<tr>

  <td valign="top" align="left"><?php echo $catid; ?></td>


  <td valign="top" align="center">

<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagesCount; $i ++) {
if ($i == $pageNumber) {
?>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="current"><?php echo $i ?></a>
<?php
} else {
?>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pages"
      onclick="showRecords('<?php echo $perPageCount;  ?>', '<?php echo $i; ?>');"><?php echo $i ?></a>
<?php
} 
} 
?>
</td>
  <td align="right" valign="top">
  Page <?php echo $pageNumber; ?> of <?php echo $pagesCount; ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And index.php

```
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Ajax codes :

```
function showRecords(perPageCount, pageNumber) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "modules/ajax.php",
      data: "pageNumber=" + pageNumber,
      cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
          $('#loader').html('<img src="loader.png" alt="reload" width="20" height="20" style="margin-top:10px;">');
      
      },
      success: function(html) {
          $("#results").html(html);
          $('#loader').html(''); 
      }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  showRecords(10, 1);
});
```

**My tries** : I've added a div with artcile id to index.php and used attr to pass it to ajax but couldn't pass it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the article id along with pageNumber that you are passing in GET request.

```
data: {pageNumber : YOUR_PAGE_NUMBER, articleId: ARTICLE_ID}
```

Do not forget to pass the articleId as 3rd parameter to the function.

Comment: I tried that `function showRecords(perPageCount, pageNumber, article_id) { data: "pageNumber=" + pageNumber + "&article_id" + article_id,` didnt make sense, same error undefined id.